# How to run a thread after another?

Tags: java, multithreading

Create three threads and the main thread. Execute each thread as simultaneous tasks. Display information when exiting each thread.

[image]

I can run two threads with above exercise, but it hard to three threads. This is my program.

```
package Thread;
```

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Test {

```
static AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("New Thread: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().toString());
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (lock.get()) {
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("First: " + i);
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Second exiting.");
                    }
                    lock.set(true);
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("New Thread: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().toString());
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (!lock.get()) {
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Second: " + i);
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Second exiting.");
                    }
                    lock.set(false);
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
}
```

}

And the result:

[image]

Can you give me some methods or tips to resolve this problem. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you want three threads to do. With two threads you have
one waiting on the bool to be false and one waiting on it to be true, right?
With three threads you need three states to wait on. You also need to be
really careful to set it up in a way so the state transitions happens exactly
in the right order and a set amount of times.

Either try to write that program, and tell us what goes wrong, or if you want
design help it might be good to tell us more about what you want to achieve in
the end.

A suggestion if you have a real multithreaded problem that needs to be solved
is to look into something like [queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). They are really nice high level abstractions
that makes working with threads much nicer.

More likely though, you have some artificial task that needs to be solved, and then
you need to speak a bit about the constraints you have.

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem, you was right, If I have more than 2 threads, I need a state variable for each thead.

Comment: Yes, either a variable for each thread, or one variable with a state for each thread. e.g. you could have an atomic integer and one thread waits on it to be 1, one on 2, etc. But that design makes it really easy to mess up I think.

Answer (score 0):

Read tutorials [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm) about `Thread` synchronization in `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

public class sync extends Thread {

```
public void run() {

    synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print("Thread Name :" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + i+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

}

class demo {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    sync obj1 =new sync();
    sync obj2 =new sync();
    sync obj3 =new sync();
    obj1.setName("First");
    obj2.setName("Second");
    obj3.setName("Third");
    obj1.start();
    obj2.start();
    obj3.start();
}
```

}

```
O/p:
```

Thread Name :First5
Thread Name :First4
Thread Name :First3
Thread Name :First2
Thread Name :First1
Thread Name :Second5
Thread Name :Second4
Thread Name :Second3
Thread Name :Second2
Thread Name :Second1
Thread Name :Third5
Thread Name :Third4
Thread Name :Third3
Thread Name :Third2
Thread Name :Third1

HOPE THIS HELPS :)